# python mysql connecting error

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

```
>>> db=MySQLdb.connect(passwd="king123",db="thangs",host="localhost",port=3306,user="user")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    db=MySQLdb.connect(passwd="king123",db="thangs",host="localhost",port=3061,user="user")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")
```

I am running it on right port , still it give me error. Can anyone give me any idea please

Comment: mysql has a nice feature where connecting to "localhost" will actually use a local unix-domain socket, not tcp. make sure python's looking in the right place for the socket file.

Comment: Do you have windows firewall enabled?

Comment: Check to see if this port is open:  TCP 3306. Thats mysqls port on windows.

Comment: Also try changing your host from localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: I am also giving the same port in my arguments

Comment: cmd prompt not showing me this port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't see this port that means mysql is not running in which case the error makes sense. Please see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html) on how to turn on the mysql server.

Comment: I have no MySQL in my program files

Comment: yes , I installed it , and it works but now it show me the error about my db "thang" 
OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'thangs'")